# bigquery dataset not found in legacy SQL only

Tags: google-bigquery

the following query does not work (using legacy SQL)

```
SELECT
      *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        ClientID,
        hitnumber,
        (
        SELECT
          cd.value
        FROM
          h.customDimensions AS cd
        WHERE
          cd.index=1 ) AS user
      FROM
        [xxxx:yyyy.ga_sessions_20180823] AS t,
        t.hits AS h
      LIMIT
        1000 )
    WHERE
      user IS NOT NULL
```

but this does (standard SQL)

```
select *
From(SELECT
  ClientID,
  hitnumber,
  (SELECT cd.value
   FROM h.customDimensions AS cd
   WHERE cd.index=1 ) AS user
FROM
  `yyyy.ga_sessions_20180823` AS t, t.hits as h 
)
where user is not null
```

i would have understood if the error was due to the syntax, but the error shown is

> Error: Not found: Dataset xxxx:yyyy

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
SELECT
    ClientID,
    hitnumber,
    -- this part
    (
    SELECT
      cd.value
    FROM
      h.customDimensions AS cd
    WHERE
      cd.index=1 ) AS user
  FROM
    [xxxx:yyyy.ga_sessions_20180823] AS t,
    t.hits AS h
  LIMIT
    1000
```

You can't use a subquery in the select list in legacy SQL, so you end up getting an error, although it's misleading. The best option is to use standard SQL for your queries, since the BigQuery team only develops features and performance improvement for that SQL dialect now.